# ORACLE PL/SQL procedure requires AUTHID CURRENT_USER for EXECUTE IMMEDIATE with DDL

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, authid

I have a PL/SQL procedure that wants to create a view with `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.

I execute the code with a user that has `CONNECT`, `RESOURCE`, `DBA` **roles**.

By default, I get the error:

> ORA-01031: insufficient privileges.

I had to explicitly add `AUTHID CURRENT_USER` to make the code execute successfully.

I think I understand the purpose of the `AUTHID` clause but here since I am executing the code with the same DBA user I wonder why I have to add the `AUTHID CURRENT_USER` clause...

Using Oracle 18c (18.3.0.0.0).

User created as follows:

```
CREATE USER zzz IDENTIFIED BY ...
GRANT connect, resource, dba TO zzz
```

Here is the code:

```
CREATE TABLE tab1 ( pk INT PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR2(50) );

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc1
--AUTHID CURRENT_USER
IS
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v1 AS SELECT * FROM tab1';
END;
/

BEGIN
    proc1();
END;
/

DROP VIEW v1;
DROP TABLE tab1;
```

The code should work without the AUTHID CURRENT_USER clause, even if (to me) it's best practice to always use that clause.

Comment: You shouldn't be using `connect` or `resource` anyway. Those two roles have been deprecated ages ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you should avoid granting predefined roles. `CONNECT` and `RESOURCE` were popular back in 7.x Oracle version. Now they have only very limited list of privileges.

`DBA`, on the other hand, is probably too powerful for user `zzz`. I'd revoke it completely, if I were you (and grant only required set of privileges, when & if necessary).

To me, it seems that your user should have been granted this:

```
grant create view to zzz;
```

explicitly. Try to do that (with `AUTHID` line removed from the procedure) and run the procedure again.

Answer (score 0):

By default (i.e. `AUTHID DEFINER`) inside a PL/SQL block you have only privileges which are granted **directly** to the user. Privileges which are granted by ROLE (e.g. `DBA`) do not apply inside a PL/SQL Block. The only exception is role `PUBLIC`, this role applies also inside a PL/SQL Block.

Run

```
grant create view to zzz;
```

Then it will work.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, granting create view privilege to the user avoids to use AUTHID CURRENT_USER.
Still, I do not understand why it works when using only indirect privilege from roles and specifying AUTHID CURRENT_USER (versus AUTHID DEFINER, the default), since the definer is user zzz ...

Comment: Maybe read [Using Invoker's Rights or Definer's Rights (AUTHID Clause)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/subprograms.htm#LNPLS00809). It might be strange but that's the way how Oracle designed it. One reason might be: A PROCEDURE, FUNCTION or PACKAGE cannot become invalid by dropping a ROLE.